# Why leveling effect is reduced when strong acid is dissolved in a weaker acid than water?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, equilibrium

I am reading a book that basically states what is the title.

This is something I observed when I was doing ICE charts: **when acid and base neutralize, we always assume complete neutralization.**

Interestingly, when we put acid in water, which can also be considered a Brønsted-Lowry base, we called it ionization of acid, and thereof acid ionization constant.

Leveling effect happens when multiple strong acids dissolve completely and we don't know which is stronger.

Here is the question: **does complete neutralization always take place with a base and an acid, why?**

Comment: your talking about strong acids - strength of acid depends on solvent

Comment: Can you make it an answer?

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6751/how-does-one-tell-if-a-specific-molecule-is-acidic-or-basic, http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/28234/what-is-the-reason-for-strong-acids-bases-dissociating-in-water?rq=1

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13855/hydrochloric-vs-sulfuric-acids-which-are-stronger-acids